# fetching values from an aggregate function - JPQL

Tags: jpql

I am trying to use a named query but it does not work:

```
      @NamedQuery(name = "Uscensuspopulationdata.fetchmostpopstate", query = "SELECT MAX(u.pop2010) FROM Uscensuspopulationdata where u.pop2010 <> 0")
```

Uscensuspopulationdata is an entity. what mistake am i doing? this is the error:

FailedPredicateException(arithmeticPrimary,{ aggregatesAllowed() }?)

Answer (score 1):

The exception isn't very descriptive, but it doesn't seem you've defined what 'u' is in the query you've shown.  Try "..Uscensuspopulationdata u where.." or a different JPA provider to see if you can get an exception that might provide more detail to help point you in the right direction.